# How can I take advantage of the secure boot technology that my laptop has?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bootloader, secure-boot

My laptop has secure boot and from what I understand it is supposed to protect the bootloader. So if my OS gets infected it won't show me any message and boot but if the bootloader is infected it will not boot up.
I want to know that if I simply install Ubuntu alongside my Windows installation from the gui installer will secure boot ALSO support my ubuntu OS and if the bootloader gets tampered with, will it refuse to boot or do I need to take some additional steps to use secure boot with ubuntu.

I believe that installing ubuntu using this method supports secure boot. Am I correct?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019

2. Will secure boot check the integrity of the bootloader in a removable device like a USB if I make the installation on that using the standard gui installer? Or should I take some additional steps?

Comment: Ubuntu the OS supports secure boot, but when kernel modules were required to be signed, any proprietary drivers (like the Nvidia video driver), will cause the boot to fail unless you go through the necessary signing yourself, for every update.

Comment: Secure boot will not let you boot any operating system, that is not signed by Microsoft's system for secure boot. Ubuntu has bought a license to put such signatures on relevant parts of its operating system. This is true also when booting from USB.